# How to make CSS overflow visible render opaque elements

Tags: css

The CSS overflow: visible property allows to render content outside the element
box. However, Firefox renders the content that overflows the box with a transparent
background that makes visible what is below it. E.g.:

```
<div style="background:red;height:30px;">
I want this to have<br>
an opaque background.
</div>
<div style="background:white">
So that it does not show what is below.
</div>
```

Is there a way of making all the contents of the first div be rendered with an
opaque background?

Answer (score 1):

**This** is one solution.

- Create a relatively positioned div, with a set height (i.e. 30px).
- Place an absolutely positioned element inside it, with 100% width/height and the opaque background image (or with css)

[**Here's the code with an example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/marko/VbqcC/)

Comment: I have tried it, but the background of the first div is still not opaque (I can see the Lorem Ipsum that is behind it).

Comment: @Angelo, isn't that what opaque means?

Comment: Well, no, "opaque" means that you cannot see thru (i.e. it does not let the light pass thru it).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv">
I want this to have<br>
an opaque background.
</div>
<div class="mySecondDiv">
So that it does not show what is below.
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.myDiv
{
background:red;
height:30px;
opacity: .75; /* Standard: FF gt 1.5, Opera, Safari */
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* IE lt 8 */
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=75)"; /* IE 8 */
-khtml-opacity: .75; /* Safari 1.x */
-moz-opacity: .75; /* FF lt 1.5, Netscape */
}

.mySecondDiv
{
background:white;
}
```

This will render your element with whichever opacity you want in most browsers (I'm not sure how many will pick this up).

Comment: I have tried it, but the piece of the first div (i.e. the second line) is still rendered on top of the second div with a transparent background in Firefox, while in IE the first div is rendered above the second with no overlapping at all.

Comment: Yeah, as per this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tchalvakspam/JUndB/ it doesn't work (chrome 22).